# Understanding an example of continuous functions with divergent Fourier series at a point on the circle

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-series

I'm reading an example of a continuous function with divergent Fourier series from Stein-Shakarchi's *[Fourier Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691113845/fourier-analysis)*. However, in the construction, I don't understand the last step (where they actually show the divergence).

They start showing this, no problem so far :

> [image]

Then they define the trigonometric polynomials :

> [image]

And show that the partial sums of the Fourier series $S_M$ satisfy

> [image]

**Now (this is what I don't understand)**, they show the divergence (in the red box), but I don't know why that inequality is true. I think I should use the first property of the sequence $N_k$ but I don't understand how.

> [image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that each $P_{N_k}$ corresponds to a sum of $2N_k$ frequencies (terms that look like $c_ne^{in\theta}$). These are the frequencies between $N_k$ and $3N_k$. Correspondingly, each $\bar{P}_{N_k}$ corresponds to a sum of $N_k$ frequencies, namely those between $N_k$ and $2N_k$.

The partial sum $S_{2N_m}(f)(\theta)$ is concerned with the first $2N_m$ frequencies of $f(\theta)$. This is more explicitly written as
\begin{align}
S_{2N_m}(f)(\theta) = \alpha_m\bar{P}_{N_m}(\theta) + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\alpha_kP_{N_k}(\theta)
\end{align}
The first term contains all frequencies between $N_m$ and $2N_m$, and the sum contains all of the rest of the smaller frequencies in $f(\theta)$.

Note (and this may take a brief review of the whole problem) that all the terms in the sum are positive, so that the following is true: 
\begin{align}
| S_{2N_m}(f)(0)| = |\alpha_m||\bar{P}_{N_m}(0)| + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}|\alpha_k||P_{N_k}(0)|
\end{align}
For the first term, we have 
\begin{align}
|\alpha_m||\bar{P}_{N_m}(0)|=|\alpha_m||\bar{f}_{N_m}(0)|\geq \alpha_mc\log(N_m)
\end{align}

(EDIT: For $\theta=0$, the sum is $0$ and the result is clear. For general $\theta$, the sum is $O(1)$ for the following reason. I don't know why the author included $O(1)$, perhaps someone can clear this up?)

Note that $P_{N_k}(\theta)$ is uniform and bounded in $\theta$ and $N_k$, so there is a constant $M$ independent of $\theta$ and $N_k$ such that 
\begin{align}
|P_{N_k}(\theta)|<M
\end{align}
and so, remembering that $\alpha_k = \frac{1}{k^2}$, we have
\begin{align}
 \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}|\alpha_k||P_{N_k}(\theta)| \leq  M \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k^2} = O(1)
\end{align}
And the result follows.

EDIT: Here is the subsequent paragraph in the text, for context

[image]

Comment: Isn't $P_N(0)$ just $0$?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that seems right. I don't get why he includes $O(1)$ then - in the paragraph after the proof is complete, he goes on to say that the term in the sum corresponding to $N_m$ has absolute value greater than $c\alpha_m\log(N_m)$ because $|\bar{P}_{N_m}(\theta)|=|\bar{f}_{N_m}(\theta)|\geq c\log(N_m)|$ (notice that $0$ has been replaced by $\theta$, see my edit). But I don't think this holds for general $\theta$.

Comment: It certainly doesn't hold for $\theta = \pi$ since $\lvert \tilde P_N(\pi) \rvert$ is the alternating harmonic series and thus converges to $\log 2$. Don't have the book handy so perhaps I'm missing some further context...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468529/series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1ne2-pi-i-n-x I think this question/answer implies that it ONLY holds for $\theta=0$. 

The book is http://prof.usb.ve/bueno/Libros/069111384X%20-%20Princeton%20University%20-%20Fourier%20Analysis~%20An%20Introduction%20-%20(2003).pdf section 2.2 on page 100 of the PDF, aka 83 in the book